# Get jsx-files to work in Visual Studio 2017 (with reactjs.NET)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I have installed Reactjs.NET (for .NET FW, not Core) and created a .jsx-file from an example on https://reactjs.net/. In my VS-->Tools-->Text Editor-->File Extensions jsx-files are listed as Typescript Editor. I can successfully run the example, but VS does not seem to recognize anything and no intellisense.

What am I missing?

[image]